# How to check with strpos if the result is a number or empty?

Tags: php

Let's say my echo sometimes:
1234
And sometimes Empty.

Is there a possibility to check if its a number?

Or to check if the result is empty?

```
echo $check;

if(strpos($check, ' check-number/empty  ') !== false){
...to do...
```

Comment: *"Is there a possibility to check if its a number?"* -- read about [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php); *"Or to check if the result is empty?"* -- if `$check` is a string then [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is the way to go; otherwise, *"empty"* has a broader meaning in PHP. Read about [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Thank you! i will read:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value using an `if-else` statement to check if current value is `null`. Use `is_numeric` to check a value is a number.

Use this:

```
   if(is_numeric($check)){ 
        echo "I am a number"; 
   }
```

As is_numeric account if a value is `null` as well. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what are you trying to do but to check if a variable is a number you can use the PHP built-in function [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)